# JQUERY Galleria css position alignment issue in Firefox. Works fine in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript, galleria

I just started using jquery Galleria for my website. I'm having an alignment issue with the div element gallery-container. In Chrome, it lines up fine, but in firefox, it is shifted to the right. See website: [www.jasonaiconnie.com/GalleryTest.php](http://www.jasonaiconnie.com/GalleryTest.php). I tried changing the position value css value for gallery-container, but it doesn't do anything. If I actually take out "pagetitle", the entire gallery is centered. Looking at it from firebug, I don't understand why the "gallery-container" is not at the same location as "gallery".

I don't know if my other css files is messing with Galleria's CSS file. Any pointers will be most welcome since I been going through the code for hours. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove 'float: left;' from 'h1.pagetitle' class in your CSS. I tested it, and the gallery went below the main title to the center of the page.

Comment: I will check that once I get home. I'm still puzzled why it would be different on firefox and chrom though. Is it firefox interpreting css scripts differently?

Comment: Hi Jason Liu, I'm not sure about the difference in interpreting between FF and Chrome, but comparing FF to IE, in most cases you would have to hack the CSS for IE to render correctly.

Comment: Hi again, I checked your website and saw that the image gallery is located where you meant it to be. ;)

Answer (score 0):

please remove float:left from class h1.pagetitle.

Thanks